# SSIS Priority of Control Flow with Precedence Constraint

Tags: sql, ssis, conditional-statements, control-flow, operator-precedence

I have 3 Data Flow tasks in SSIS Control Flow: T1, T2 and T3.  They should be running from T1 to T2 to T3. However, T2 should be running only at the beginning of one month while the other two run every day.

So I added precedence constraints as follows:

[image]

For constraint from T1 to T2, expression is as below:

[image]

For the other two constraints, they're configured as "Logical OR":

[image]

My question is: when expression is "True", in what sequence will they execute? Will it be T1-->T2-->T3 or T1--> T2 and T3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `OR` constraint will execute as soon as one of the upstream components succeeds.

So in this case T2 and T3 will execute simultaneously.

Simple workaround, put T1 and T2 in a sequence container.  The sequence container will succeed whether or not T2 is run, then move to T3.